# Windows 10: Can I add 'Move To' to right click menu option for a file in Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management, context-menu

There is a Move To icon in the Explorer Toolbar. Is it possible to add this functionality to the right click menu for each file (somewhat analogous to the 'Send To' option)?

I seem to recall there were some either undocumented or -very- arcane command strings one could do to access various file functions to right click, but I can't seem to find them now on the Interwebs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`
2. Create a new key under `ContextMenuHandlers` with the value `{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}`.
3. Restart. Now you should have a *Move to folder* option.

**Always remember to take a backup of the registry before making any changes.**

Comment: Thanks. Where is this documented?

Comment: You can get a lot of tweaks from [this old website](http://www.mdgx.com/newtip22.htm). Many tweaks appear to be dead, but it can used if you know the workaround. I might as well recommend [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx) page and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you want to know more.